# file upload through VF page to external ftp site?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a request to increase the file  size upload limit from existing 5 MB  to 25~50MB. The functionality currently uses  a VF page to upload the file to an external ftp server. We changed the external server side setting to accept the file upto 50 mb however it seems  VF page still cannot upload file that exceed 8 mb. How can I increase the limit at Visualforce page? I understand  that VF page has a limit of 10 mb  for file upload but  here I  am trying to upload file through VF that redirects  to another ftp location.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to increase the limit. It's a hard limit. Instead, consider using the [AJAX Proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_proxy.htm), which should be able to handle files of arbitrary size (I've tested it with files in excess of 100MB). As long as you can read the file in JavaScript, you'll be able to send the file to your server.

Comment: Thanks for getting back ...I checked the code . so basically the Visualforce page is  simply using iframe component to redirect to an external ftp server where actual upload is  happening. Does  this  still  go through  the internal Apex limits?  I  don't  see  apex:inputFile component  being used  anywhere which  would  limit it  to 10 MBs...

Comment: @sfdclearner If there's an iframe, there shouldn't be any limit other than the end server. Have you checked it as well?

Comment: <apex:pageblock id="theblock">
<apex:pageblocksection id="thesection" columns="1">
<apex:IFRAME id="theiframe" src="https://xxx.someftpserver.com/fnfileuploader/Upload.aspx?SalesForceDocID={!Some_Documents__c.id}" width="100%" height="300" >

</apex:IFRAME>
<apex:inputHidden id="fnid" value="{!Some_Documents__c.FileNetId__c}"/>
</apex:pageblocksection>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: The ftpserver  is a third  party  and  they  did  confirm  that  they have increased  the limit  at their end but still  we are not able to upload  the bigger file